# Get certain values from a JSON file using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I've seen a lot of questions about JSON and PowerShell these past hours and none helped me find a solution to this particular problem. And I'm sure it's something easy.

I want to extract all the `url` fields of the `plugins` objects in this JSON object (original URL is this: https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json):

```json
{
    "connectionCheckUrl": "http://www.google.com/",
    "core": {
        ...
    },
    "deprecations": {
        ...
    },
    "generationTimestamp": "2021-05-19T12:16:52Z",
    "id": "default",
    "plugins": {
        "42crunch-security-audit": {
            "buildDate": "Oct 06, 2020",
            "defaultBranch": "master",
            "dependencies": [
                ...
            ],
            "developers": [
                ...
            ],
            "excerpt": "Performs API contract security audit to get a detailed analysis of the possible vulnerabilities and other issues in the API contract.",
            "gav": "io.jenkins.plugins:42crunch-security-audit:3.8",
            "issueTrackers": [
                ...
            ],
            "labels": [
                ...
            ],
            ...
            "title": "42Crunch REST API Static Security Testing",
            "url": "http://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/42crunch-security-audit/3.8/42crunch-security-audit.hpi",
        },
        "AnchorChain": {
            ...
            "url": "http://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/AnchorChain/1.0/AnchorChain.hpi",
            ...
        },
        ... many hundreds more ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The `plugins` object contains one object per plugin, where the plugin's name is the object's key. So I somehow have to iterate over all plugin objects and look for the `url` property.

I want/have to do this using PowerShell (v5.1) but cannot find an easy way. Here is where I am stuck:

```powershell
$all = (Get-Content(".\update-center.json") | convertfrom-json)
$all.gettype().fullname

$plugins = $all.plugins
$plugins.gettype().fullname
```

I get this result:

```
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

And now I hope to iterate over the individual `plugin` objects and simply get the `url` key's property, but I'm stuck:

```powershell
$plugins | get-member -MemberType NoteProperty | foreach name | foreach $plugins.$_.url
```

The `get-member` is supposed to get the individual plugins I suppose, but hours of poring over PowerShell documentation have clearly fried my brain. Help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, not exactly sure. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
$Json = Invoke-RestMethod https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json
$Json = $Json -replace '^updateCenter.post\(|\);$' | ConvertFrom-Json

$plugins = $Json.plugins

foreach($prop in $plugins.psobject.properties.name)
{
    $plugins.$prop.url
}
```

#### Output

```
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testingbot/1.16/testingbot.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testinium/1.0/testinium.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testlink/3.16/testlink.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testng-plugin/1.15/testng-plugin.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testodyssey-execution/2.1.5/testodyssey-execution.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testopia/1.3/testopia.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testproject/2.10/testproject.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testquality-updater/1.3/testquality-updater.hpi
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/testsigma/1.3/testsigma.hpi
....
....
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus of retrieving the actual file and removing the JSONP cruft. It is also very clear and easy to follow. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Import your JSON as you did for `$all`

Then, use `$all.plugins | gm -MemberType Properties | select -expandproperty Name | %{ $all.plugins.$_.url}` to get your list of urls

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like that it's a one-liner, but maybe it's a bit too succinct and cryptic even though it works. :-) Some explanation would surely help to more appreciate your work.